# Gridview Item Loaded Multiple Times

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I made a GridView for a gallery activity in my app, and I've noticed strange behavior when the activity is first started. I included a print statement that tells me when each image is loaded, and this is the output I'm getting:

```
01-30 17:27:09.597 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.607 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.607 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.607 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.707 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.707 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.707 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.707 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.707 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.707 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_24_07_146 into slot 1
01-30 17:27:09.707 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_24_34_369 into slot 2
01-30 17:27:09.717 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_24_38_530 into slot 3
01-30 17:27:09.717 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_24_45_214 into slot 4
01-30 17:27:09.717 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.717 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.717 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.717 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.787 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.787 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.787 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
01-30 17:27:09.787 25390-25390/com.thomas.galleryapp I/System.out: Loaded gallery_img_2016_01_30_17_23_59_197 into slot 0
```

It seems that no matter how many items are put into the GridView, item 0 is loaded multiple times, usually between 15-25 times. Why does it keep reloading the first item? Here's the xml for the GridView:

```
<GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

For the Grid items:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.thomas.galleryapp.Views.SquareImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/selectedCheckbox"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My custom SquareImageView class:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

    public SquareImageView(final Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

And the image adapter for the Grid:

```
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater galleryItemInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        galleryItemInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = galleryItemInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
        }
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        if (fileList.size() > 0){
            imageView.setImageBitmap(fileList.get(position).getImage());
            System.out.println("Loaded " + fileList.get(position).getFileName() + " into slot " + position);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return fileList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: try logging position in the getView to see if it is 0, if not there is a problem with your backing data., it means it contains dupe items

Comment: Try public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

Comment: @Elltz I logged the position in the getView and it was 0

Comment: @tiny sunlight I changed the getItemId method to return the position, but that didn't change anything

Comment: getView gets called multiple times, always.

Comment: @TheSunny it's only getting called multiple times for the first item

Comment: This is normal behaviour. Build a new app with a listview or griview and the associated adapter will behave the same.

Comment: really? all the time it was zero? wow, im puzzled, try this `imageView.setImageBitmap(fileList.get(position+i).getImage());` where i is an int variable declared outside your getview. this is just to diagnose the problem. also post your whole main activity code.